# How to use keras in python 3.6 (miniconda) installed through RStudio keras::install_keras()?

Tags: python, keras, rstudio

I successfully installed keras in RStudio on Windows. By default it installed miniconda with python 3.6 and all the required packages.

I would like to use keras directly in python with the same installation. But when I run python from command line and then `import keras` I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

I do see keras-2.1.6-py36_0 directory in pkgs.

Please help how I can solve this without breaking keras installation in RStudio.

Comment: how did you install. using `pip install keras` ?

Comment: No, I installed from RStudio (see title). Nothing more. In RStudio keras runs without problems (it uses keras in python as backend).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not done yet, you need to do this :

```
conda install keras
```